# ElasticSearch 7.10 using pit return duplicate ids in differnt pages

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-7, point-in-time

ElasticSearch 7.10 using pit return duplicate ids in differnt pages using pagination with page number and page size, this makes sence? I thougt that pit should prevent the effect of indexing new documents while doing searches

Comment: what field are you sorting base on? it has unique value?

Comment: I have a documnt with genearted unique _id and a companyId, I do a match search with  only the companyId and get results with the same _id returning more than once

Comment: Do you mind showing your query?